# Making req object available to every view file

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node Express web project using Pug views.

By using the [Response.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) object, I can make the Express `Request` object (`req` in my code) available to every pug file:

```
const app = require("express")();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.req = req;
    next();
});
```

Are there any side effects of using this approach and what are the disadvantages?

The convenience I get is that any view file can have access to all properties of the `Request` object, eg the query string, etc, without having to pass them explicitly using the textbook method like:

```
app.get("/xx", (req, res) => {
    res.render("xx", { query: req.query });
});
```

Comment: The `req` is a context (dynamic) object that is created when an HTTP request is handled by express. So your question is a bit confusing to me, Can you elaborate a little bit more about your needs?

Comment: A front-end person wanted to read the query string parameters from any pug view file, even if the router did not explicitly passed it to the view file. I did a test, and `req.query` in the pug file did contain the query string parameters as a nice Javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any side effects of using this and what are the disadvantages? Does it use up a lot of memory?

There are no side effects of using a template engine with express. Actually you can use [`res.render`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) instead.

---

> The convenience I get is that view files can have access to the query string,

If we know `req.query` has what we need that leaves the question is **How to resolve the template for each route?**

We will need to split the solution into two parts.

- Part One - Genital request handle.

Although the response is dynamic the request resolving is known. Let say we have an additional parameter on the `req` object `req.template` and as we sad `req.query` is available as well.

The below function will render the `req.query` into `req.template` and send the response.

```
function pugTemplateHandler(req, res) {
   const compiledFunction = pug.compileFile(req.template);
   res.send(compiledFunction(req.query));
}
```

We don't care about **Method** nor **Routes** here. We expect that `req` to be set before this is called.

- Part Two - Resolve the template file according to the route and method

Above we promised `pugTemplateHandler` that `req` will be ready for it. We can use Middleware to set the members we need on the `req` object.

```
app.get('...', (req, res, next) => {
    req.template = 'PUG_TEAMPLATE_PAT';   // resolve template
    // req.query = { ... };               // add or overwrite use params
    next();
}, pugTemplateHandler);                   // pass modified req

app.post('...', (req, res, next) => { ... }, pugTemplateHandler);
app.put('...', (req, res, next) => { ... }, pugTemplateHandler);
app.del('...', (req, res, next) => { ... }, pugTemplateHandler);
```

Because we know the HTTP **Method** and the **Route** resolving the template is easy. Most likely here the template will be a static string.

The solution is extendable and has respect the idea of separation of concerns.